# How to use repository in Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to get the id number of an item an update that item. However at the moment this is what I have. Not sure how to do the issuerepository. I have updated the question and getting this error  Severity Code
'Employee' does not contain a definition for 'Entry' and no extension method 'Entry' accepting a first argument of type 'Employee' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

And this 
error   An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property Issue getIssue = IssueRepository.GetEmployeeById(id);

Employee Class

```
 public class Employee
{


    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Employee Number")]
    public int employeeNum { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Employee First Name")]
    public string firstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Employee Last Name")]
    public string lastName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Employee Department")]
    public string department { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Employee Name")]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {



            return string.Concat(firstName, " ", lastName);
        }

    }


    [Display(Name = "Logged in as:")]
    public string LoggedInUserName { set; get; }
    [Display(Name = "Approved By:")]
    public string ApprovedByName { set; get; }



  public class IssueRepository : IIssueRepository, IDisposable
{
    private Employee context;

    public IssueRepository(Employee context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public Employee GetEmployeeById(int id)
    {
        return context.employeeNum.Find(id);
    }

    public void UpdateEmployee(Employee employee)
    {
        context.Entry(employee).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

public class IIssueRepository
    {

```
    public interface IssueRepository : IDisposable
    {
        Employee GetEmployeeById(int employeeNum);
        void UpdateEmployee(Employee employee);

        void Save();
    }
}
```

public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {

```
        Issue getIssue = IssueRepository.GetEmployeeById(id);
        return View(getIssue);


    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the changes submitted from the user and updates the Item in the List  
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="issue"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// 

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Issue issue)
    {


        if (ModelState.IsValid)

        {

            _issueRepository.UpdateEmployee(issue);

            _issueRepository.Save();

            return RedirectToAction("IssueItem", issue);
        }


        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Please make sure you have filled in all required fields.");
        }

            return View(issue);


        }
```

Comment: You have the interface but no implementation.  First change your interface name to IIssueRepository to follow naming conventions.  Then create a class called IssueRepository that implements IIssueRepository with a GetEmployeeById method.  This should be code that calls the DB and returns an Employee object.

Comment: Could you please help me out, I dont know where to go from there

Comment: so IIssueRepository  should be in the issue class or a different?

Comment: Read through this walkthrough: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-dependency-injection

Comment: You have not initialized `_context`. And does `Employee` have a employeeNum property (with a `Find()` method)? Show us the Employee class.

Comment: no it does not have a find method. what should be in that method?

Comment: Show us the Employee class

Comment: You never instantiated, "_content" it's just a reference with no object. That's why you are getting, "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property "

Comment: what should i instantiate it to

Comment: As Jasen pointed out, are you using Entity Framework? If so I have little experience with that Framework.  You need to initialize it to a new Employee object that needs to be passed to the constructor: "IssueRepository(Employee context)"    I am having trouble understanding how this code you have is more of an intermediate level coding, and you are struggling with these basic concepts.

Comment: Also as pointed out earlier, employeeNum property is of int which doesn't contain a "Find()" method.

Answer (score 0):

Start with a class called IIssueRepository:

```
  public interface IIssueRepository : IDisposable
    {
        Employee GetEmployeeById(int employeeNum);
    }
```

Create a class called IssueRepository:

```
  public class IssueRepository : IIssueRepository
    {
        public Employee GetEmployeeById(int employeeNum)
        {
            // go get the data and return an employee object
        }
    }
```

Comment: what am I doing wrong to be getting those error messages

Comment: This won't work:  Issue getIssue = IssueRepository.GetEmployeeById(id), it needs to be Issue getIssue =_issueRepository.GetEmployeeById(id);